# AJAX GridView Not Updating

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview

I am using a update panel and placing the SqlDataSource as well as the GridView inside the contenttemplate

i've set timercontrol as the asyncpostback trigger but the gridview does not update when i change a record from the related table in sqlserver plus what seems even more crazy is that the deleted record still shows up in the grid view when i do refresh(full post back of page)
Also i've disabled caching for the datasource however this aint wrking HELP!!!!!

here's my code

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 
      Inherits="_Default" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>





    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

    <ContentTemplate>
    <div id="ajx">
    <div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:busConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [reserv]" EnableCaching="false" CacheDuration="0" CacheExpirationPolicy="Absolute" EnableViewState="false"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SeatNo" HeaderText="SeatNo" 
                    SortExpression="SeatNo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">

        </asp:Timer>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>

    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1"/>
    </Triggers>



    </asp:UpdatePanel>




    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually databind the datasource and gridview on each tick of the timer.
Add the following to your Timer1_Tick event:

```
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *declarative method*?

Comment: declarative meaning i wanna use the aspx markup(without the code tags ofcourse(<% %>) and not the codebehind method,so that i dnt hav to use ado.net to bind the dataset or datatable in codebehind as u suggested.

Comment: I don't see how that will be possible, you can physically write the onClick inside the aspx file (if you don't have a .cs codebehind file) but this way or that, you're going to need this to run as code and not with tags.

Comment: I thought putting the controls under update panel will re initialize them as in fullpage postbacks i guess i will hav to use code newayz thanx :>